# How to know the hostname/IP address of the computer who is doing changes in the shared folder on server

Tags: c#, shared-directory

I have to monitor a shared folder on the server for changes taking place in that folder by a computer connected in the network(it's hostname). I implemented monitoring of directory and files using C#. But, it only monitors events like Created, Renamed, Changed, Deleted and Error events. 
I also need help with monitoring the hostname/IP address of the computer accessing or doing changes to the shared folder and the time when the event took place.
Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace a1ashiishFileSystemWatcher
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public ListBoxlistBox;
        public const String startMonitoring = “Start Minitoring…”;
        public const String stopMonitoring = “Stop Minitoring…”;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Create a listBox to show activities of all Events.
            listBox = new ListBox();
            listBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
            listBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 121);
            listBox.Name = “listBox”;
            listBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(571, 238);
            listBox.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Controls.Add(listBox);
        }
        private voidbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create FolderBrowserDialog object.
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            // Show a button to create a new folder.
            folderBrowserDialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            DialogResult dialogResult = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();
            // Get selected path from FolderBrowserDialog control.
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolderroot = folderBrowserDialog.RootFolder;
            }
        }
        private voidbutton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher object.
            FileSystemWatcher fsWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            switch (button2.Text)
            {
                // Start Monitoring…
                case startMonitoring:
                    if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
                    {
                        listBox.Items.Add(“Started FileSystemWatcher Service…”);
                        fsWatcher.Path = textBox1.Text;
                        // Set Filter.
                        fsWatcher.Filter = (textBox2.Text.Equals(String.Empty)) ? “*.*” : textBox2.Text;
                        // Monitor files and subdirectories.
                        fsWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
                        // Monitor all changes specified in the NotifyFilters.
                        fsWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                                                 NotifyFilters.CreationTime |
                                                 NotifyFilters.DirectoryName |
                                                 NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                                 NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                                 NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                                 NotifyFilters.Security |
                                                 NotifyFilters.Size;
                        fsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                        // Raise Event handlers.
                        fsWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
                        fsWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
                        fsWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnDeleted);
                        fsWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
                        fsWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
                        button2.Text = stopMonitoring;
                        textBox1.Enabled = false;
                        textBox2.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listBox.Items.Add(“Please select folder to monitor….”);
                    }
                    break;
                // Stop Monitoring…
                case stopMonitoring:
                default:
                    fsWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                    fsWatcher = null;
                    button2.Text = startMonitoring;
                    textBox1.Enabled = true;
                    textBox2.Enabled = true;
                    listBox.Items.Add(“Stopped FileSystemWatcher Service…”);
                    break;
            }
        }
        // FileSystemWatcher – OnCreated Event Handler
        public voidOnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add event details in listbox.
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox.Items.Add(String.Format(“Path : “{0}”   || Action : {1}”, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType)); });
        }
        // FileSystemWatcher – OnChanged Event Handler
        public voidOnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add event details in listbox.
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox.Items.Add(String.Format(“Path : “{0}”   || Action : {1}”, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType)); });
        }
        // FileSystemWatcher – OnRenamed Event Handler
        public voidOnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add event details in listbox.
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox.Items.Add(String.Format(“Path : “{0}”   || Action : {1} to “{2}””, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType, e.Name)); });
        }
        // FileSystemWatcher – OnDeleted Event Handler
        public voidOnDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Add event details in listbox.
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox.Items.Add(String.Format(“Path : “{0}”   || Action : {1}”, e.FullPath, e.ChangeType)); });
        }
        // FileSystemWatcher – OnError Event Handler
        public void OnError(object sender, ErrorEventArgse)
        {
            // Add event details in listbox.
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { listBox.Items.Add(String.Format(“Error : {0}”, e.GetException().Message)); });
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this approach, but still I am not able to get the hostname. Please help me where I am going wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace MonitorShare
{
    public partial class Monitor : ServiceBase
    {
        public Monitor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string dDirectory = @"E:\SharedFolder\Shares";
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(dDirectory);
            string[] filePath = Directory.GetFiles(dDirectory, "*.*");

            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.BeginInit();
            watcher.filePath = dDirectory;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 

NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Changed);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Created);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_Deleted);
            watcher.Filter = "*.*";
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.EndInit();
        }

        protected void watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "openfiles.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/query /FO CSV /v";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            try
            {
                process.Start();
                if ((process.StandardOutput != null))
                {
                    var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim().Replace("\"", 

"");
                    var lines = result.Split('\n');

                    var firstLineIndex = 1 + lines.Cast<string>().ToList().FindIndex(l => 

l.Contains("Hostname"));
                    for (var i = firstLineIndex; i < lines.Count() && firstLineIndex > 0; i

++)
                    {
                        var fields = lines[i].Split(',');
                        var time = DateTime.Now;
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\SFD\log.txt", FileMode.Append);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

                        if(firstLineIndex.ToString()=="Hostname")
                        {
                             Console.SetOut(sw);
                             Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath + "\t" + e.ChangeType + "\t" + 

time + "\t" + e.Name + "\t" + fields[0]);
                             sw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                process.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "openfiles.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/query /FO CSV /v";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            try
            {
                process.Start();
                if ((process.StandardOutput != null))
                {
                    var result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim().Replace("\"", 

"");
                    var lines = result.Split('\n');

                    var firstLineIndex = 1 + lines.Cast<string>().ToList().FindIndex(l => 

l.Contains("Hostname"));
                    for (var i = firstLineIndex; i < lines.Count() && firstLineIndex > 0; i

++)
                    {
                        var fields = lines[i].Split(',');
                        var time = DateTime.Now;
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\SFD\log.txt", FileMode.Append);
                        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

                        if(firstLineIndex.ToString()=="Hostname")
                        {
                             Console.SetOut(sw);
                             Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath + "\t" + e.ChangeType + "\t" + 

time + "\t" + e.Name + "\t" + fields[0]);
                             sw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                process.Close();
            }

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not possible with `FileSystemWatcher` and not from another machine in the network. I guess you have to look into putting that code on the machine sharing that folder and check relevant Windows APIs if it is possible at all to monitor this.

Comment: Do you *really* need the machine/IP from where the change came in or is it in fact more interesting to get the *User* who did it? My guess would be that the latter is easier.

Comment: @Fildor Yes, we require to identify the client machine's hostname on the server which are making changes to the shared folder

Comment: Maybe have a look into the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1286137/982149 It's from 2009 and about Users, so I am deliberately NOT marking it a duplicate.

Comment: This is not a problem you should solve in your code. If you want to register which user makes changes to a shared folder on a server, you need to configure auditing on that server. You can then read the audit log on that server. A FileSystemWatcher is not the solution to this problem.

Comment: @CodeCaster I already tried auditing. When I perform auditing on the server, it gives me the Server's name as the user instead of the client name who made the changes

Comment: @beginner Why do you want the hostname of the machine.  What value does that provide?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340.aspx) to at least get the ones which are connected to the share. You need to reference `System.Management.dll`, create an instance of `ManagementObjectSearcher` and there you go.

The problem is usally finding the correct classes, the reference for WMI can be found here under [WMI Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa394572.aspx). For your use case you will need the [Win32_ConnectionShare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa394109.aspx) class. Take into consideration that the application needs to run with admin priviledges in order to access data from that class.

A little example code for your use case (according to the above mentioned documentation `antecedent` represents the server side while `dependent` represents the client side):

```
// Create a query
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ConnectionShare");

// Initialize an object searcher with this query
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

// Get the resulting collection and loop through it
foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
{
    string antecedent = mo["antecedent"].ToString();
    string dependent = mo["dependent"].ToString();

    ManagementObject share = new ManagementObject(antecedent);
    ManagementObject server = new ManagementObject(dependent);

    Console.WriteLine(server["UserName"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(server["ComputerName"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(server["ShareName"].ToString());
}
```