# Trigger when the user is deleting a file

Tags: c#, windows

In order to play a sound my c# program has to trigger every time the user deletes a file via the explorer in windows.

How can I do this? Is this even possible?

**Edits:**

To clarify: I want this to be some kind of a system hook. So it should not matter where the file is deleted.

I tried this:

```
m_watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
m_watcher.Path = @"C:\";
m_watcher.Filter = "*.*";
m_watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
m_watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

m_watcher.Deleted += M_watcher_Deleted;

private void M_watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("deleted");
}
```

but the problem is that I cant find out if M_watcher_Deleted is called as a result of a direct user action like pressing delete in the explorer. This is important because I want to play a sound. And if I am not able to differentiate between user actions and background actions with temporary files the sound will play all the time.

Comment: I suggest to search for FileSystemWatcher.Deleted.

Comment: Read this API the sample program does something very similar to what you want : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is a good place to start. Ill take a look at it.

Comment: The Field.watcher works fine, but how to find out if the user himself deleted the file or this was done from some automatic system stuff? E.g. When creating a textfile a file somewere else gets deleted (The file is: "C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\Neues Textdokument.txt.lnk")

Comment: please explain in more detail why you can't use `System.Io.FileSystemWatcher` and what you want to achieve. maybe share some of the code you already tried. have a  look at [ask]

Comment: @user1859022: I edited my question. But I am afraid the answer is "This is not possible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect any file deletion **and** if you want to know if it was by the user or not, then it's currently not possible in any .Net implementation regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286137/which-user-caused-filesystemwatcher-events).

`FileSystemWatcher` does not receive any hint on the origin of that deletion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no separate API for "file system actions initiated by the user" and "file system actions initiated by some automatic system". It shouldn't be too surprising, since there's no objective way to judge the difference in the first place.

If I use explorer to move a file, is that a user action or a system action (I said "move file", not "copy here, delete there")? If I have a piece of text editing software and save a file, is that user action or system action? If the editor also saves a backup file, is that a user action, or a system action? If the OS also keeps its own file history?

I think we can agree that there is a sliding scale here - the first case is the most obviously user-related, and the last most obviously "behind the scenes". But they're *all* initiated by the user. And that's just with a single file being "directly" acted upon.

The system doesn't keep track of the series of decisions and actions that led to a file system operation (and if it did, good luck interpreting that in any useful fashion). It does know about which process initiated the operation, for example, but that's not something you should take into account outside of debugging. Just because an operation was initiated by `explorer.exe` doesn't mean that it comes from the user dragging a file from one place to another in Explorer.

You need to think about what kind of service you want to provide to your user. Thinking about why I would every consider a feature like this useful, the first thing that comes to my mind is that you shouldn't care about how exactly a file was deleted, but rather, where the file *was* - that is, having a list of directories that you keep watch of. If I (or something else!) deletes a file from my documents, that might be worth my attention; if I (or something else) delete a file from the Temp folder, why should I care?